# Writing Integration Tests for gRPC in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, grpc

our backend is a bunch of gRPC microservices that talk to each other, and I want to write integration tests against each of the services. My plan was as follows:

1. Set up a python unittest similar to this: https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/847b3fd8-1e81-4a0e-b975-5a855390f98e/y
2. Send it example requests and verify that the responses look sane.

This all seems fine, except due to fact that we live in a micro-service world and we even rely on 3p REST APIs, testing is a bit more painful than this. I was planning to mock out these dependencies and provide reasonable request / response pairs for each. I had a couple of questions about this:

1. Is it possible to use monkey-patching-type of mocks with gRPC unittests in python? Based on the example tests I'm seeing, they seems to be spinning up local gRPC service instances and I wasn't sure if I added the @patch annotations, it would actually override the corresponding libraries.
2. Another approach I was considering was converting our service to use a context-object design pattern (injected into the Servicer). The context-object will hold the stubs to the other microservices / rest APIs, and then I can just inject mocks / fakes as I see fit through this new context object. Between the 1st approach and this one, what have folks seen to be more maintainable in the long-run? I come from a C++ background and so monkeypatching is very weird to me, but I do know it's a norm in python-realm.
3. Any other advice from an integration testing standpoint? The use of mocks feels a bit weird, but we've already hit a few cases where contracts between modules with a gRPC service weren't being tested (since mocks were used instead) and as a result breakages happened. Cross-microservice testing still needs to happen, however that's also non-trivial. We still need a way to mock out the 3p calls (any advice / reading here would also be much appreciated).

Thanks!

Comment: Consider setting up a test environment outside of the unit tests. You can then run actual calls against this. That said, I feel you when you say that monkeypatching is weird for a C++ programmer. Mocking requests that go to other systems is a regular case in integration testing, just as mocking dependencies ("dependency injection", read about it if you don't know it!) is regular in unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for the input! One follow-up - let’s say I mock requests and responses to other services in each test, doesn’t that mean that each test would need to be intimately familiar with how the internals of the service orchestrate and call those backends? It feels like the tests will start looking unreadable. Not sure if this is an issue in reality.

Comment: Yes, that is a valid concern. At some point, you will write tests where the mocks just repeat what the code does. So, running them will not give you any valuable info about your code, because both could be wrong. However, changing the code doubles in effort, because you have to apply the same changes to the tests, too. This can happen. Maybe it's easier to increase the scope of those tests then, like including an actual instance of the mocked system.